# How to overload template class method for another template type?

Tags: c++, templates

What is the standard method in C++03, without using Boost, to either:

1. Overload a template class method where the template type only appears in the return value of the method, or
2. Specialize a template class method for another templated type.

In other words, how can this be made to work:

```
template <typename T, int N> struct Vector { T x[N]; };

struct Sampler
{
    template <typename T>
    T next() {
        // Do some work and return a value of type T.
        return T();
    }

    template <typename T, int N>
    Vector<T, N> next() {
        // Do some different work and return a value of type Vector<T, N>.
        return Vector<T, N>();
    }
};

int main() {
    Sampler sampler;
    sampler.next<double>();
    sampler.next<Vector<float, 2> >();
    return 0;
}
```

As written, both uses of `next()` call the first method, while I'd like the second use to call the second method.

Comment: Since both methods call the default c'tor, you don't need the second in the case presented.

Comment: @StoryTeller The return value is just to make the code compile, don't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're asking for partial specialization of template functions. That's not in the language, but you can emulate it with tag dispatching or class templates. Here's an example with tag dispatch:

```
template <typename T> struct tag{};
struct Sampler
{    
    template <typename T>
    T next() {
        return next(tag<T>());   
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    T next(tag<T>) {
        return T();
    }

    template <typename T, int N>
    Vector<T, N> next(tag<Vector<T,N> >) {
        return Vector<T, N>();
    }
};
```

Then you use it like this:

```
sampler.next<double>();
sampler.next<Vector<double,2> >();
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad0d2e00dad256da)

Note that you need a space between the last `> >` tokens in the second line before C++11.

Comment: This is literally what I was about to post :)

Comment: Thank you, I had the suspicion that a tag would help here. I suggest making `tag` private to the class, and removing the superfluous parenteses in the public `next()` method. (They are superfluous, right?)

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune yeah, making `tag` private is a good idea if you're not going to use this idiom anywhere else, and even then it can avoid pollution. You're right about the parentheses; I was overzealous with my most-vexing-parse avoidal ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an helper struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct SamplerHelper
{
    T operator()() const 
    {
        std::cout << "T\n";
        return T();
    }
};

template<typename T, int N>
struct SamplerHelper<Vector<T, N> >
{
    Vector<T, N> operator()() const 
    {
        std::cout << "vec\n";
        return Vector<T, N>();
    }
};

struct Sampler
{
    template <typename T>
    T next() {
        return SamplerHelper<T>()();
    }
};
```

A [working example is available on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/af58gnAknMmcl3cL).

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks, fixed.

Comment: The only downside of this approach is that it requires splitting the class into three pieces; in my case this isn't possible, which is why i accepted the other answer instead. But this is a nice and perfectly valid answer to my question so I upvoted it.